# IFrame "allowfullscreen" attribute not working in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, iframe

I am trying to set the `allowFullScreen` attribute of an `IFRAME` using Javascript as follows:

```
media_element = document.createElement("IFRAME");
media_element.src = "//www.youtube.com/embed/" + getId(media_link);
media_element.allowFullScreen = true;
```

However, this does not work in Google Chrome. When I try to launch the video in full screen mode, I get `This video is not available in fullscreen` error. I haven't been able to find an attribute to set that works in Chrome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
media_element.setAttribute('allowFullScreen', '')
```

not

```
media_element.allowFullScreen = true
```